# Can't delete a row from a Database using a img PHP

Tags: php, mysql, row

i was doing a backoffice for my website, and to show the data i brought a table from database to show all the upgrades requested from users, and i was thinking about putting 2 images , one for update and another for deleting that same row..

```
                              # Table from Database #

?>

<div id="DBForm">

<p id="title"  align="center"> Upgrades</p>
<br/>
<?php
$resultado=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM upgrades");

if (mysql_affected_rows()>=1)
{
   echo "<table class='DBTable'>";
   echo "<tr>

            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Upgrade</th>
            <th>Morada</th>

            <th>Contacto</th>
            <th>NIF</th>

            <th>Factura</th>
            <th>Data</th>
            <th>N Serie</th>
            <th>Cupao</th>
            <th>Alterar</th>
            <th>Eliminar</th>

         </tr>";

    while ($linha=mysql_fetch_array($resultado))
    {
        echo "<tr align='center'>
                <td>".$linha["nome"]."</td>   
                <td>".$linha["upgrade"]."</td>
                <td>".$linha["morada"]."</td>                                   
                <td>".$linha["contacto"]."</td>
                <td>".$linha["nif"]."</td>                              
                <td>".$linha["factura"]."</td>
                <td>".$linha["data_factura"]."</td>                              
                <td>".$linha["n_serie"]."</td>  
                <td>".$linha["cupao"]."</td>                
                <td><a href=\"alterar.php\"><img src=images/alterar.png></img></a> </td>
                <td><a href=\"eliminar.php\"><img src=images/eliminar.png></img></a> </td>

              </tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}

?>

</div>
```

It was all right, but when i press the img to delete, the browser says that i sucessfully deleted the row but when i go back to the page the row is still there, what it could be ?

```
                           #Code from img to delete the row#




$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "loja";
$tbl_name = "upgrades";

// Create connection
mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password)or die ("Não houve conexão");
mysql_select_db("$dbname");

$id=$_REQUEST['id'];

$sql="DELETE FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

if ($result)
{
    echo "Registo apagado com sucesso!";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<a href='upgrades.php'> Voltar a upgrades </a>";
}
else
{
    echo "ERRO!";
    mysql_close();
}



?>
```

Comment: `$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());` and use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - Plus, where is `$_REQUEST['id']` being populated from?

Comment: You are not attaching the id to your links, should be something like: `<a href=\"alterar.php?id='.$linha["id"].'\">`

Comment: @Steve I think you meant `<a href=\"eliminar.php?id='.$linha["id"].'\">` pretty sure "eliminar" means to "eliminate" in their language (delete) ;-) and "alterar" to "alter" maybe as in "update".

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. It's awful and is being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. Always be absolutely **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) because you have several severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) here.

Comment: <a href=\"eliminar.php?id=".$linha["id"]."\">  this worked thanks guys so much, really appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing is supplying this value:

```
$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
```

The page is being requested with just a link:

```
"<a href=\"eliminar.php\"><img src=images/eliminar.png></a>"
```

In order to supply the identifier you'll need to add it to the link.  Maybe something like this:

```
"<a href=\"eliminar.php?id=".$linha["id"]."\"><img src=\"images/eliminar.png\"></a>"
```

(or whatever the identifier is on `$linha`)

---

Additionally, please be aware that your code is wide open to **[SQL injection attacks](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)**.  You'll want to look into using prepared statements instead of putting user input directly into SQL code.

Sidenote: You can safely remove the `</img>` tag; it's not a valid tag.